# Update to 13.10 and mixed-up linux headers (kernel: 3.8.0-32-generic, headers: 3.11.0-12-generic)

Tags: kernel, 13.10

I've updated to 13.10 from 13.04 and I've problem with linux headers.

this is the kernel version:

```
uname -a 
Linux xxx-dell 3.8.0-32-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 22:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Li
```

and those are installed headers:

```
dpkg -l | grep headers
linux-headers-3.11.0-12                   3.11.0-12.19
linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic           3.11.0-12.19
```

I've tried to install headers for 3.8, but this ends with error:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.8.0-32-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-3.8.0-32-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

How can I download matching headers to my kernel? 
Is is possible that upgrade process did not update to last kernel version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the package was left out of the saucy repository. For what its worth I downloaded them manual from these links and installed.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/linux-image-3.8.0-31-generic

http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/linux-headers-3.8.0-31